# How to print every array element?

Tags: java

I have an array contains Employee object.

How do I print every element of the array?

I can only get it to print the last input.

```
/*This is Employees class
  toString accepts lastname, firstname, payrate, workhour, grosspay, tax, netpay, and return a string */
public void display(Employee a[])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<max; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i].toString());
        }
     }

// main
        for (int a=0; a<max;a++)
        {
            list[a]=emps.getinfo(emp);
        }
        emps.display(list);

//Employee class
//  I am assuming there is something wrong with these two methods in my Employee class. 
public Employee(Employee e)
        {
            lastname=e.lastname;
            firstname=e.firstname;
        }
// Argument will be lastname, firstname, workhour, payrate, grosspay, tax and net.
public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("format", argument);
        }
```

The following link is the complete code.
https://imgur.com/gallery/bTXPSKb

Input

```
qwe , ewq 5 5
rtw , gtr 7 7
```

Output

```
rtw ,gtr 7.00 7.00 49.00 7.35 41.65 
rtw ,gtr 7.00 7.00 49.00 7.35 41.65
```

Expecting

```
qwe ,ewq 5.00 5.00 25.00 3.75 21.25
rtw ,gtr 7.00 7.00 49.00 7.35 41.65
```

Comment: Where do you set the properties of the Employee instances?

Comment: In the employees class.

Comment: I don't see it in the code you posted. Also, please post the Employee class.

Comment: I post the Employee class. As for the properties of the Employee instances, are you asking for the constructors of Employee?

Comment: Please post complete code. Including the instance variables of Employee class, including the actual body of `getInfo`.

Comment: You are probably printing correctly but the elements in your list/array are duplicates of each  other (or the same instance).

Comment: I post a link to the complete code above the input. It seems like I cannot edit image into my post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question regardless of code context:

```
Integer[] integers = {1, 2, 3};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
```

looks like problem in

```
list[a]=emps.getinfo(emp);
```

most likely emp remains the same during your loop, so you get the same result. Your link does not provide any info, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you write your array as List for more generic use of the object. 
it's a better practice this way, and now you can rock-n-roll with it like this:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("A");
items.add("B");
items.add("C");
items.add("D");
items.add("E");

//lambda
//Output : A,B,C,D,E
items.forEach(item->System.out.println(item));

//Output : C
items.forEach(item->{
    if("C".equals(item)){
        System.out.println(item);
    }
});

//method reference
//Output : A,B,C,D,E
items.forEach(System.out::println);

//Stream and filter
//Output : B
items.stream()
    .filter(s->s.contains("B"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```